# Pandorabots - send an email

Tags: aiml

Good Day.
Is it possible for a chatbot to send an email (or run a script or pageurl that sends an email) invisibly (preferably) to the visitor when reaching some goal?
For example, the visitor asks a callback and after the chatbot receive his phone - this phone must be send to the person who will call the visitor.
Is it possible?

Yes I want to use PHP for this. But how can I send command to PHP file without clicking button and open this file?
Tried this:

```
<category>
    <pattern>TESTSENDPHONE *</pattern>
    <template>
        SEND PHONE
        <oob><url>http://website/send_email.php?message=<star /></url></oob> 
    </template>
</category>
```

not work.

Can a chatbot to send data to the Internet (any way - any language)? For example, using Javascript (AJAX), which is already used in chatbot, or any other language (method)?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on something similar here which may help:
https://discover.bot/bot-talk/aiml-tutorial-survey-questions/

To send an email invisibly, you'll need to look at the mail function of PHP. This article should help:
https://tecadmin.net/send-email-using-php-script/

Alternatively, someone should be checking the bot conversation logs to manually pick out such details and contact your customers. You'll see the phone numbers etc in the logs.

Comment: Yes I want to use PHP for this. But how can I send command to PHP file without clicking button and open this file?

Comment: I would make a category asking the user if they wanted to send their details to your sales team and include a YES button for them to click on to call your PHP script. Sorry but I'm not a PHP expert and can't help you further on that side of it.

Comment: The problem is that the person has already agreed to be called. Without this permission, it makes no sense to ask him for a contact phone number. Therefore, asking him a question with a similar meaning once again is not very appropriate (it will look absurdly). Can a chatbot to send data to the Internet (any way - any language)? For example, using Javascript (AJAX), which is already used in chatbot, or any other language (method)? Can I write my own Javascript function and run it from AIML code (or other way)?

Comment: As I understand, the <OOB> tags do not work for a chatbot and the <oob><urlget>http://website.com/send_email.php?message=<star /></urlget></oob> will not work in chat - right?

Comment: That's right. OOB is "out of band" and should be handled by your interface. For example, in the Flash version of Mitsuku, I have categories that load other things such as magic tricks and games. This sort of thing isn't handled by the interpreter itself.

Comment: Too bad. This way I can't offer to install your chat on my clients websites  - since these are e-commerce websites and it is very important for website owners to quickly get customer data and contact them. Without this possibility  it's just an interlocutor bot. I hope this opportunity appears in the nearly future. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most people create their own interfaces to handle OOB. That way, they can customise them to have their own corporate branding. For example, it would be unusual for a huge company to want to have the Pandorabots logo at the bottom. 

Documentation for the Pandorabots API is here: https://home.pandorabots.com/dash/help/docs